# Amazon S3 | Do lifecycle management considers the upload date or the last access date?

Tags: amazon-s3, lifecycle

I'm configuring my application S3 Lifecycle Management but only with Amazon's documentation, I couldn't get it if what is considered before moving the data to a lower tier is the upload date or the last operation made on the data.

For example, let's consider I configured the Lifecycle Management to lower the tier of the data after 30 days. I have a data that was uploaded 40 days ago, but I handle it every day. Will S3 lower consider the time I uploaded the data or the last time I handled it?

If by default it uses the upload date, there is a way to configure S3 to consider the last handle date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the object "upload date" or "creation date" or "last modified date". It's not currently supported to configure the S3 Lifecycle Management to use the last *access* date.

You might be able to get the last access date by doing some SQL queries on S3 access logs, and then perform the transition manually. However, this seems pretty painful.

A better way to do this might be to maintain a DynamoDB table which records the last access time. Then you can create a cron job to perform the transition periodically.

Another simpler approach is to use the [S3 Intelligent-Tiering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-dynamic-data-access). Feel free to take a look, and it might fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I understood that Intelligent Tiering takes into account also the access date, right?

Comment: @TiagoBachiegadeAlmeida yep